# When a function modify an external variable

Tags: python, variables

In python, for example if I write:

```
def f(x,y):
    x.append(y) #1
    x += [y]        #2
    x = x+[y] #3
    return x
x=[]
y=3
z=f(x,y)
```

Only the operations 1 and 2 modify the value of x (that will be [3,3])
Why? 
There's a general rule?

Comment: Actually operation 2 will cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

Python's `list` class defines `__add__`, which controls the behaviour of `x + y`, and it defines `__iadd__`, which controls the behaviour of `x += y`. The implementations of these specify that `x + y` creates a new list, and `x += y` modifies the list `x`. Presumably these seemed like the most likely intention of people using those operations.